# Get raw HTML code of element with Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

Html structure:

```
   <div id="product">
     <p>some text</p>
     <p>some text2</p>
   </div>
```

My PHP code:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
echo $crawler->filter('#product')->text();
```

returns:

```
some text some text2
```

But I need:

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text2</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is one but ugly way - via iterating over its nodes:

```
$html = '';

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    $html.= $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML();
}
```

Or, in your case, you should iterate over filtered element:

```
$html = '';     
$product = $crawler->filter('#produkt');
 
foreach ($product as $domElement) {
    foreach($domElement->childNodes as $node) {
        $html .= $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
    }
}
```

From [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#component-dom-crawler-dumping)

Comment: $html contains full code of page. I need get code of element.

Comment: @damour so just iterate over filtered content - updated my answer